# Nonlinear second-order ODE $yy''+(y')^2=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the ODE:

$$yy''+(y')^2=x$$

Comment: What is $(y y')'$ ?

Comment: The LHS is the derivative of $yy'$, and we get $yy'=\frac{x^2}2+C$ where $C$ is a constant. Now, note that $2 yy'$ is the derivative of $y^2$.

Comment: That's correct Davide! So that the general solution is \\
$$y^2=\frac{1}{3}x^3+Ax+B$$ 
an elliptic curve. Indeed I put this ODE which I solved by\\ using 
$(yy')'=(y')^2+yy''. 
I put this ODE as I want to know people with dominion about\\ 
nonlinear ODE's. But the ODE I haven't been able to solve is\\ 
$$yy''+y'=x$$,
maybe you have an interesting idea at respect. Thanks so much!\\

Comment: Are you saying that even though your question is about $yy''+(y')^2=x$, the equation you really want to know about is $yy''+y'=x$? If so, why didn't you ask about the equation you really wanted to ask about?

Answer (score 1):

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives 
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{x^2}{2}+y'y=C_1
\end{equation*}
where we have used the reverse product rule and $C_1$ is a constant. Solve for $y'$ and multiply both sides by $2y$ to get
\begin{equation*}
2y'y=x^2+2C_1.
\end{equation*} 
Integrate both sides with respect to $x$ to get
\begin{equation*}
y^2=\frac{x^3}{3}+2C_1x+C_2
\end{equation*}
where $C_2$ is another constant. Take the square root. $~_{\square}$